# Meaning of TV Backlight LED strip details

Tags: led, led-strip, tv

I am learning electronics and I just disassembled a broken TV with the purpose of reconverting it into a smart light lamp.

The issue is that I don't understand the details of the backlight LED strips. Could I get some help? I cannot get to find the manufacturer datasheet.

I would like to understand every detail, but the critical questions are:

- What voltage should I input?
- Can I dim the light?
- What's the current being used?

I did some measures with a multimeter and got that when the TV is OFF there is **39.5V** and **0A** and when it is ON, **44V** and **1.91A**, but I wanted to double-check it with the specs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 44 V at 1.9 A = about 80 W. This seems very high for a TV. It looks like three strips in parallel. If the strips have series resistors then you may be able to use a constant voltage PSU. If not you'll need constant current. Trace out the circuit and add it into your question using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: I wonder why the TV broke after only 4yrs?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 maybe that's the "best before" date ... lol

Answer (score 1):

LEDs are like Zener diodes and these 8S3P power LEDs are drawing 84W according to your measurements, so the backplane provides a good reflector of light and radiator of heat dissipation required to operate them with a reasonable warm temperature rise.

You can use the same power supply and possible figure out how to dim the current with some control signal or feedback signal pot as I imagine they are exceptionally bright.

It appears each white LED is very efficient but drawing  3.5W and is composed to 2 series white LEDs in each chip. Thus each string is matched by supplier quality to be only 5.5V per dual LED, which is implies to me they are very efficient with low series resistance at full brightness and very high resistance at the leakage voltage threshold of 39.5V at about <100uA.

That explains to you why the voltage range from off to full brightness has a small range in voltage. They are like very powerful Zener diodes.

> What voltage should I input?

- same as what you measured up to 44V

> Can I dim the light?

- only if you can show the interface signal that controls the current then figure how to make that using the same power board repackaged to power the LEDs in a safe manner.

> What's the current being used

- up to the same as what you measured.